# Test Bench Waveform no longer on Xilinx....Need VHDL guidance

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, waveform, xilinx-ise, object-test-bench

MAJOR UPDATE.  NEVERMIND. I FOUND AN OLDER VERSION OF XILINX ISE SUITE IN THE FORM OF A TORRENT.  THE OLDER VERSION HAS TEST BENCH WAVEFORM.   I REALLY DISLIKE THEIR BUSINESS MODEL OF DISCONTINUING CERTAIN APPLICATIONS WHICH MAKE THE PROCESS EASIER.

My issue is that I am working a Simple Machine Schematic Circuit which and trying to display is waveform under certain conditions. However Im using the latest Xilinx ISE which does not have Test Bench Waveform ( i cant seem to download old version on Windows 8.1).

I have been struggling to learn the correct VHDL. This is the generated VHDL that I have.

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE ieee.numeric_std.ALL;
LIBRARY UNISIM;
USE UNISIM.Vcomponents.ALL;
ENTITY top_top_sch_tb IS
END top_top_sch_tb;
ARCHITECTURE behavioral OF top_top_sch_tb IS 

   COMPONENT top
   PORT( Q1 :   OUT STD_LOGIC; 
          RCO   :   OUT STD_LOGIC; 
          INPUT :   IN  STD_LOGIC; 
          PRE   :   IN  STD_LOGIC; 
          CLK   :   IN  STD_LOGIC; 
          Q0    :   OUT STD_LOGIC);
   END COMPONENT;

   SIGNAL Q1    :   STD_LOGIC;
   SIGNAL RCO   :   STD_LOGIC;
   SIGNAL INPUT :   STD_LOGIC;
   SIGNAL PRE   :   STD_LOGIC;
   SIGNAL CLK   :   STD_LOGIC;
   SIGNAL Q0    :   STD_LOGIC;

BEGIN

   UUT: top PORT MAP(
        Q1 => Q1, 
        RCO => RCO, 
        INPUT => INPUT, 
        PRE => PRE, 
        CLK => CLK, 
        Q0 => Q0
   );

-- *** Test Bench - User Defined Section ***
   tb : PROCESS
   BEGIN
      WAIT; -- will wait forever
   END PROCESS;
-- *** End Test Bench - User Defined Section ***

END;
```

These were the conditions that I was going to use test bench for...but need a VHDL equivalent.

> Open the HDL Bencher window. In the Initialize Timing window, select
>   the option Single Clock. Set Clock High Time and Clock Low Time to 50
>   ns, Input Setup Time and Output Valid Delay to 10 ns, and Initial
>   Length of Test Bench to 2500 ns. After checking the values, click on
>   Finish.

I have found different VHDL language sites... but I cant really clarify anything. IF more detail is needed I will try to supply it.

Comment: Which tool and version do you have?  Starting in 11.1, Xilinx® no longer supports the [Test Bench Waveform Editor](http://www.xilinx.com/itp/xilinx10/isehelp/ism_c_tb_overview.htm). Xilinx points to [XAPP199](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/application_notes/xapp199.pdf) and design and simulation guides for various tool releases. From a practical perspective any suggestions on how to test a component would be predicated on knowing what it does, and the function or your `top` isn't readily apparent from it's interface list.

Comment: My "top" was a circuit schematic. Perhaps me posting it would help??   And thank you for the the XAPP199 link.  I am trying to utilze it now for my clock.